# Empty Virtual Functions in Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have inherited some code which contains the following classes/functions (as well as others).

Base Class

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void erase() {};  
    virtual void draw() {};      
}
```

Derived Class 1

```
class Der1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void erase();  
    virtual void draw();      
}
```

Derived Class 2

```
class Der2 : public Der1
{
public:
    virtual void erase();  
    virtual void draw();      
}
```

The Base class contains two virtual functions, erase() and draw() which are empty, i.e. they do nothing at that level.

The Der1 class inherits from Base and implements these functions, i.e. a Der1 object has executable code within erase() and draw().

The Der2 class inherits from Der1 and again implements these functons in its own way.

When one of these Der2 objects is instantiated, the code executes the constructors for the Base class first, then the Der1 class and then the Der2 class.

What I'm experiencing is that occasionally, I get a crash which, through debugging, points me to the "erase()" function within the Base class being null, or seemingly uninitialised (i.e. erase() has value 0x00000000).

Other times, when the code works as expected, this function has a valid memory address and is non-null.

I can't see how this could possibly occur, so if anyone else has ever seen anything like this, perhaps they could shed some light on it?

Thanks again

SRB

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to call these functions on an object that has already been destroyed? We would need to see a [mcve].

Comment: Aren't you calling the `erase()` function from constructor of one of these classes?